# Meaning of "down beside" in this context

Tags: prepositions

In a book of **children's poem** I found:

> Twenty froggies went to school
>   **Down beside** a rushy pool, 
>   .........

Being a learner I am having trouble understanding the need for the word **down** with **beside.**

Is it here for **making the line look good?**

Please explain the usage of **down** here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question and perhaps one which should be migrated to *English Language & Usage*.

The OED sense 3 of the adverbial uses of ***down*** says the following:

> 3. a. Without connotations of descent through space. To or at a place or locality regarded as lower in position; in a southerly direction or
>    position; to or at a distance from the capital or other centre.

**Now this does not explain the *down* which you have identified - though it is starting to get close to it. However, sense 3c** says:

> **3c. Preceding a prepositional phrase of place, without the implication
> that this is lower in position or further south: at a moderate
> distance from a point of reference; off, away.**

A couple of examples may help explain this:

> **1970   A. Buzo Front Room Boys i, in Plays 20   If I were one of the back room boys, you wouldn't see me here before noon. *I'd be down by
> the pool***.
>
> **2010   Times 11 Dec. (Sat. Review section) 1  He was an enthusiastic
> reader, *down at the local library* three times a week.**

**It sort of carries an implication of being away from where one might usually be - often suggesting at leisure. It may be difficult for a non-native speaker to understand, but if you need further help I will let you have some more examples.**

Answer (score 0):

There is, as you indicate, some latitude given in poetry so that the rhythm, etc., sound good. I think part of good poetry is making the words natural regardless, but that's a different topic.

I've always taken "down" in this sort of use to mean that the pond was slightly downhill of its surroundings; either it's in a hollow of sorts or just behind a hill or something. Bodies of water are usually downhill of their surroundings in some dimension and to some extent; that's why the water collects there.

Comment: *He was down at the pub drinking with his friends* does not necessarily suggest it being downhill. See my answer.